# How to Format Search String to Return Part of Search String From More Than One Column in Razor Page Table?

Tags: asp.net, search, razor-pages

I have a data table that I would like to filter via a Search box on my razor page.

Here is my current code:

```
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            referral = referral.Where(s => s.BoardMtgMonth.Contains(searchString) || s.BoardMtgYear.Contains(searchString));
```

So, one column in the table (BoardMtgMonth) has month values: January, February, March, etc
The other column (BoardMtgYear) has year values: 2013, 2014, 2020, etc

I need to make my search return values for a pairing of those 2 values. If a user types in March 2020, I would like all rows from the table that have a BoardMtgMonth value of March AND a BoardMtgYear value of 2020 to be the search result.

Right now,
If I type in March: I get all rows that have a March month.
If I type in 2020: I get all rows that have 2020 for their year.
If I type in March 2020: I get NO returned values.

How do I change the format of my Search String so that it accepts an AND combination search? Ie, BoardMtgMonth = March AND BoardMtgYear = 2020? Is there something other than the 2 pipes || I should be using?

Thanks for any and all assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your search string to include both values separated by a delimiter, such as a space character. You can then use the `Split` method to split the search string into an array of strings, and use the `Contains` method to check if the values in the table match the values in the search string.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    string[] searchValues = searchString.Split(' ');
    referral = referral.Where(s => s.BoardMtgMonth.Contains(searchValues[0]) && s.BoardMtgYear.Contains(searchValues[1]));
}
```

The `Where` checks if the `BoardMtgMonth` column contains the first value (=> month value) **AND** the `BoardMtgYear` column contains the second value in the `searchValues` array (=> year value).

As Example `January 2023` will split  into `January` and `2023`.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    string[] searchValues = searchString.Split(' ');
    if (searchValues.Length == 1)
    {
        referral = referral.Where(s => s.BoardMtgMonth.Contains(searchValues[0]) || s.BoardMtgYear.Contains(searchValues[0]));
    }
    else
    {
        referral = referral.Where(s => s.BoardMtgMonth.Contains(searchValues[0]) && s.BoardMtgYear.Contains(searchValues[1]));
    }
}
```

This would combine the single and multi value search.

Comment: Thanks so much. Just what I needed! Very clear explanation. Just needed that help with the syntax. :)